# Node - console.log(req.body) -undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola amigos estoy tratando de imnprimir una respuesta por consola, que recibe mi app en **node** y que estoy mandando desde **Postman** , pero cuando me imprime en consola me da el objeto **undefined**.

> Server Started. ___ in port:3000
>   undefined

Este es mi código

```js
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');

var app = express();
//var path    = require("path");
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
const port = 3000;

//engine & configuration
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home/index');
});

app.post('/test/product', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send({message:'Producto se ha recibido'});
});



serv.listen(port);
console.log('Server Started. ___ in port:' + port);
```

Alguien sabe como puedo "definirlo"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el siguiente codigo, Primero tienes que instalar

> body-parser

Instalalo así en tu directorio de trabajo:

> npm install --save body-parser

El codigo ya lo adapte a que use la libreria para parsear el body de formularios y bodys de tipo json.

Espero te sirva.

```js
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');// instalar: npm install body-parser

var app = express();
//var path    = require("path");

//Parsear el body usando body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // body en formato json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //body formulario

var serv = require('http').Server(app);
const port = 3000;

   //engine & configuration
   app.engine('ejs', engine);
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home/index');
});

app.post('/test/product', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send({message:'Producto se ha recibido'});
});



serv.listen(port);
console.log('Server Started. ___ in port:' + port);
```